# The Ctrl+D feature to copy a line in dolphindb GUI

Tags: dolphindb

The Ctrl+D feature to copy a line in dolphindb GUI

Is there a feature like Ctrl+D to copy a line in dolphindb GUI interface? If no, can it be added?

Answer (score 0):

Seems "Ctrl+D" can delete a line. The feature to copy a line has not been developed, but can be equipped in future.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29787540)